# Re-trigger bootstrap tab change event

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I've got a screen that looks as follows:
[image: agency screen]

The tabs get loaded via ajax calls on the tab change event. The grid on top of the page needs to be able to trigger the show event of a specific tab (as it supplies an id, etc...), but it only works for the first item clicked, almost like the second click gets prevented.

Simplified code

```
$(function() {

    var self = this;

    self.agencyId = -1;

    self.SwitchView = function(partialViewName, targetDiv) {
        alert('Switching To ' + partialViewName)
    };

    $("#AgencyTabs").tab();
    $("#AgencyTabs").on("show", function(e) {

        var target = "#partialContainer";
        var partialViewName = $(e.target).data("src");

        self.SwitchView(partialViewName, target);

        $("#AgencyTabs").tab();
    });



    $('#toolbar').on('click', '.action-button', function() {

        var iGrid = this;

        self.agencyId = $(iGrid).data('rowid');
        self.currTab = "Details";

        $('#AgencyTabs a[data-src="' + self.currTab + '"]').tab('show');

        return false;
    });


    $('#AgencyTabs a[data-src="Parameters"]').tab('show');

});​
```

I've set up this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rohan_buchner/87gLC/) to demonstrate my problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Is this what you need?](http://jsfiddle.net/87gLC/5/)

```
$("#AgencyTabs").on("show", function(e) {
    var target = "#partialContainer";
    var partialViewName = $(e.target).data("src");

    //self.SwitchView(partialViewName, target);

    $("#AgencyTabs").tab();
});

$("#AgencyTabs").on("click", function(e) {
    self.SwitchView($(e.target).data("src"), e.target);
});
```

From what I understand, the problem was that `SwitchView` wasn't being executed when the tab was already selected. This edit fixes that, by moving the function execution from the `onshow` event to the `onclick` event.

**Edit:**

[The fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87gLC/5/) now executes `SwitchView` on the "View" button, also. However, it doesn't specifically fire the `onshow` event, it just calls the function.

Edit to $('#toolbar').on('click', <...>); :

```
$('#toolbar').on('click', '.action-button', function() {

    var iGrid = this;

    self.agencyId = $(iGrid).data('rowid');
    self.currTab = "Details";
    self.targeted = $('#AgencyTabs a[data-src="' + self.currTab + '"]')

    self.SwitchView(self.currTab, self.targeted);

    self.targeted.tab('show');

    return false;
});
```

Comment: I've got a temp workaround, e.g by having a placeholder tab that i can swap to... but it feels like a hack. so not sure if its the best way

Comment: @RohanBüchner: I've edited in some code to execute the function from the "view" button. Is that what you need?

Comment: Seems like it does the trick, just need to implement it. thanks :)

Comment: No problem, glad to be of help.